# jq: select where .attribute in list

Tags: arrays, json, jq, membership

In python I can do:

```
>>> 5 in [2,4,6]
False
>>> 5 in [4,5,6]
True
```

to determine if the give value `5` exists in the list. I want to do the same concept in `jq`. But, there is no `in`. Here is an example with a more realistic data set, and how I can check for 2 values. In my real need I have to check for a few hundred and don't want to have all those `or`ed together.

```
jq '.[] | select(.PrivateIpAddress == "172.31.6.209"
                 or
                 .PrivateIpAddress == "172.31.6.229")
        | .PrivateDnsName' <<EOF
[
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-209.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.209"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-219.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.219"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-229.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.229"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-239.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.239"
    }
]
EOF
```

Answer (score 14):

### using `,`

I don't know where in https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/ this is documented. But the answer is in that `jq` does implicit one-to-many and many-to-one munging.

```
jq '.[] | select(.PrivateIpAddress == ("172.31.6.209",
                                       "172.31.6.229"))
        | .PrivateDnsName' <<EOF
[
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-209.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.209"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-219.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.219"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-229.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.229"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-239.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.239"
    }
]
EOF
```

(the formatting/indenting of code was made to match that of the OP to simplify visual comparison)

The output is:

```
"ip-172-31-6-209.us-west-2.compute.internal"
"ip-172-31-6-229.us-west-2.compute.internal"
```

"Seems like voodoo to me."

### using `| IN("a","b","c")`

**Update:** It's been 16 months, and I've finally learned how to use the `IN` function. Here is a demo that will produce the same results as above.

```
cat > filter.jq <<EOF
# Either of these work in jq < v1.5, but I've commented them out since I'm using v1.6
# def IN(s): first( if (s == .) then true else empty end ) // false;
# def IN(s): first(select(s == .)) // false;

.[] | select(.PrivateIpAddress | IN("172.31.6.209","172.31.6.229")) | .PrivateDnsName
EOF

jq -f filter.jq <<EOF
[
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-209.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.209"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-219.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.219"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-229.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.229"
    },
    {
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-6-239.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.6.239"
    }
]
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks to @pkoppstein for the help with this one! https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/370#issuecomment-395577269

Answer (score 2):

> But, there is no `in`.

You could use `index/1`, as documented in the manual.  Even better would be to use `IN`, which however was only introduced after the release of jq 1.5.  If your jq does not have it, you can use this definition for `IN/1`:

```
# return true or false as . is in the stream s
def IN(s):
  first( if (s == .) then true else empty end ) // false;
```

If you want to check membership in an array, say $a, simply use `IN( $a[] )`.

Comment: It's Peter Koppstein! I hit the <kbd>Run</kbd> button on https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons and did the "Value Iterator equal to group" test and was surprised by the result. https://jqplay.org/s/b2g7Rkiq0G I see what it's doing. But where is the **why** documented?

Comment: In the official documentation, see "Comma: ,".  If you have time, let me know what you think of this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15MKv7VsHAZBoubxekGX-uhYGBQ50eaIDUqYZWREqhAc/edit?usp=sharing